# Json reading the Api

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I have this json ruby on rails generated with jbuilder

```
{
 "code": "success",
 "place": [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "El Guaton",
     "branches": [

    ]
   },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Pollo Loco",
  "branches": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "branch_name": "Sucursal arica",
      "schelude": "lunes a domingo 10:00 a 24:00 horas",
      "adress": "angamos 1115",
      "feature": "Local De Gran espacio  con Eventos",
      "city": {
        "city": "Arica",
        "created_at": "2013-12-15T19:12:43Z",
        "id": 3,
        "region_id": 3,
        "updated_at": "2013-12-15T19:12:43Z"
      },
      "latitude": "-18.478042",
      "longitude": "-70.310667",
      "barcode": "mForqSLGdX",
      "type_place": {
        "created_at": "2013-12-15T19:13:03Z",
        "id": 2,
        "place_name": "Temático",
        "updated_at": "2013-12-15T19:13:03Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "branch_name": "sucursal cambio",
      "schelude": "lunes a domingo 24 horas",
      "adress": "los pajaritos",
      "feature": "lugar muy amplio",
      "city": {
        "city": "Concepción",
        "created_at": "2013-12-15T19:12:35Z",
        "id": 2,
        "region_id": 2,
        "updated_at": "2013-12-15T19:12:35Z"
      },
      "latitude": "12.77",
      "longitude": "33.666",
      "barcode": "IqyXwFDyAZ",
      "type_place": {
        "created_at": "2013-12-15T19:13:42Z",
        "id": 4,
        "place_name": "Restaurant",
        "updated_at": "2013-12-15T19:13:42Z"
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Sibaritico",
  "branches": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "branch_name": "Sucursal Viña Centro",
      "schelude": "lunes a viernes 11:00 a las 21:00",
      "adress": "4 norte #523",
      "feature": "Local De Gran espacio  con Eventos",
      "city": {
        "city": "Viña del Mar",
        "created_at": "2013-12-15T19:12:19Z",
        "id": 1,
        "region_id": 1,
        "updated_at": "2013-12-15T19:12:19Z"
      },
      "latitude": "-33.019171",
      "longitude": "-71.55284",
      "barcode": "LjsLuFHoFI",
      "type_place": {
        "created_at": "2013-12-15T19:13:42Z",
        "id": 4,
        "place_name": "Restaurant",
        "updated_at": "2013-12-15T19:13:42Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

I read it with the following code

```
function pedirDatos(){

    $.ajax({
    url: "http://bajon.herokuapp.com/api/get_places.json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(place){ 
    for(i in place['place'])
                {alert(place['place'][i].name);
                alert(place['place'][i].branches[i].branch_name);

                    }

                },

            error:function(data){
                 alert('Error');
                }
            });

}
```

first alert: alert(place['place'][i].name); // get "El Guaton" next "Pollo Loco" and finally "Sibaritico" all fine..but the second alert don't get data :( .
How do I retrieve data from branches?.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to iterate the branches array with the places array iterator. You need a separate iterator for the branches array.

```
for (var i = 0, l = place.place.length; i < l; i++) {
                alert(place.place[i].name);
    for (var k = 0, len = place.place[i].branches.length; k < len; k++) {
                alert(place.place[i].branches[k].branch_name);
    }
}
```

That will produce

```
El Guaton 
Pollo Loco 
Sucursal arica 
sucursal cambio 
Sibaritico 
Sucursal Viña Centro
```

[Operational JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9RPq/)